# Partitioning 18 into odd number of even components

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

I need to find a total number of ways $18$ can be partitioned into odd number of even components.

Does the function below satisfy the "odd number of components" requirement?
$$
P_{1,3,5,7,9}(X) = \frac{1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^3} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^5} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^7} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^9}
$$

Given that $n$ is even, then every partition of $n$ has an even number of odd parts.
Can it be said that if $n$ is even, then every partition of $n$ has an odd number of even parts?

How can I add to that the requirement that components are supposed to be even?
I have spent 6 hours reading about self-conjugation, odd and distinct parts and generating functions and I'm clueless.

Comment: $18=2+4+6+6$ would be an example of a partition of $18$ into an even number of even parts

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^3} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^5} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^7} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^9}$ is a generating function for the number of partitions into parts of $1,3,5,7,9$, so odd-sized parts rather than an odd number of parts

Comment: Isn't this the same as partitioning $9$ into an odd number of components?

Comment: @KeithBackman - that point was in the second paragraph of my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be quickest to just write the numbers down: you should be able to find $16$ cases.

$$18 =2+2+14=2+4+12=2+6+10=2+8+8=4+4+10 \\=4+6+8=6+6+6  =2+2+2+2+10=2+2+2+4+8\\=2+2+2+6+6=2+2+4+4+6 
=2+4+4+4+4 \\= 2+2+2+2+2+2+6=2+2+2+2+2+4+4 \\
=2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2$$

One approach could be to say that, by dividing each part by $2$, the number of ways $18$ can be partitioned into an odd number of even parts is equal to the number of ways $9$ can be partitioned into an odd number of parts of any parity.  That just pushes the issue further down to a question which has been considered slightly more.  [OEIS A027193](https://oeis.org/A027193) enumerates these but does not in my view give a simple expression for finding the number of such partitions.

The easiest one to use that I know is that the number of ways $n$ can be partitioned into an odd number of parts is $p(n-1^2)-p(n-2^2)+p(n-3^2)-\cdots$ where $p(n)$ is the total number of partitions of $n$.  So here in the case of $n=9$ you get $p(8)-p(5)+p(0) = 22-7+1=16$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. What would be  the course of action if n is odd? Would the answer be 0? Odd number cannot be partitioned into odd number of even parts because it cannot be partitioned solely into even parts at all, right?

Comment: @Betech41 - Yes. If the question had been  number of ways $19$ can be partitioned into odd number of even components, then the answer would have been $0$ for the reason you give.

Comment: But what about the number of ways 19 can be partitioned into even/odd number of odd parts? I know that the number of partitions into odd parts is equal to the number of partitions into distinct parts but how do I count the number of partitions into distinct parts algebraically?

Comment: $19$ cannot be partitioned into an even number of odd parts, so you would be asking for the number of ways 19 can be partitioned into odd parts (necessarily an odd number of them).  That happens to be the same as the number of ways it can be partitioned into distinct parts.  That number is $54$ as shown in [OEIS A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009)